# checking for words from an Array and also get them when they have caps

Tags: discord.js

I have a system for my automoderation so it will make a var called newContent that will remove all whitelisted words from my array in censorlist.json and after will check if there are any bad words left and if there are delete the message. But my censorlist is like this

```js
{
  whitelist: [
    "word",
    "word"
  ]
}
```

and if someone's message contains for example "hello word" it will make the var newContent "hello  " but if it contains for example "Hello WORD" the var newContent will be "Hello WORD" cause it doesn't censor it. My code to define newContent;

```js
            let newContent = censorList.whitelist.filter(v => message.content.includes(v)).reduce((a, v) => a.split(v).join(''), message.content);
```

Thanks for the help already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply sanitize your user input via the [`String.Prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method in JavaScript and add only lowercase words to your censorlist like so:

```js
let newContent = censorList.whitelist.filter(v => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(v)).reduce((a, v) => a.split(v).join(''), message.content.toLowerCase());
```

and the object being:

```js
{
  whitelist: [
    "word",
    "word",
    ] // make sure to add only lowercase words in this array.
}
```

So even if the user input is WoRd **or** WORD it would do the intended stuff!